# Problem with ASCII Rotating Cursor (TUI) Animation

Tags: c++, command-line-interface, progress-bar, tui

I'm trying to create the rotating cursor animation thing.

Each time I compile this I always get a slash (or two) left at the end, and the backspace character does not work. I used two ways to do this: the sleep function and the chrono timer and they worked very similarly and left a slash after spinning, ignoring the backspace character.

This works differently and as expected if I leave out any newline character or manipulator.

```
    void spinningCursor() {
   for (int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) 
   { 
       cout << "-" << flush;
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10));
        cout << "\b" << flush;
        cout << "\\" << flush;
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10));
        cout << "\b" << flush;
        cout << "|" << flush;
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10));
        cout << "\b" << flush;
        cout << "/" << flush;
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10));
        cout << "\b" << flush;
   } 
}
```

Or...

```
void spinningCursor2() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        cout << "-";
        cout.flush();
        usleep(10000);
        cout << "\b";
        cout.flush();
        cout << "\\";
        cout.flush();
        usleep(10000);
        cout << "\b";
        cout.flush();
        cout << "|";
        cout.flush();
        usleep(10000);
        cout << "\b";
        cout.flush();
        cout << "/";
        cout.flush();
        usleep(10000);
        cout << "\b";
        cout.flush();
    }
}
```

main function...

```
int main() 
{ 
  spinningCursor();
  cout <<"\nHello, World!"<< endl;
  spinningCursor2();
  cout <<"\nHello, World, Again!"<< endl;
   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: This is probably very terminal specific. What operating system are you working on? What terminal?

Comment: Also, the flushes after the backspaces shouldn't be needed.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I used the powershell (with bash) terminal, the windows Visual studio terminal and the Visual studio Code bash terminal. All the same results also removing the newline character seems to fix it, but I need it starting in a new line. An extra backspace character does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output effect is not guaranteed but dividing it into sections might help.

Idea:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

using namespace std::chrono_literals; // a cumbersome way to be able to write 100ms

// unformatted output of one char, a backspace, flushing and Zzz...
void slow_put(char ch) {
    static const auto delay = 100ms;
    static const char bs = '\b';
    std::cout.write(&ch, 1);
    std::cout.write(&bs, 1);
    std::cout.flush();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(delay);
}

// newline, but erase the char under it first
void nl() {
    std::cout.write(" \n", 2);
}

// proxy ... decorate stuff here (for debugging etc)
void display(char ch) {
    slow_put(ch);
}

// enabler to repeat a bunch of sequences
void spinner(const std::string& sequence) {
    // execute the display function for one char at a time
    std::for_each(sequence.begin(), sequence.end(), display);
}

// example use of the helpers above
void spinningCursorSchema(size_t times) {
    static const std::string seq = R"raw(|/-\)raw"; // the pattern to display

    while(times--) spinner(seq);
    // add more patterns to this schema if wanted
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Spinner: [ ]\b\b";
    spinningCursorSchema(100); // run the spinningCursor 100 times
    nl(); // erasing newline
}
```

---

Edit: A brief explanation:
For every group of functions you called that I *felt* could be named, "`do_this()`" or "`do_that()`" I put them in a function and named them accordingly.

The purpose of this exercice was not primarily for me to find the error in your code but to provide a frame of reference. It's easier to identify/talk about/fix problems when one can say "your `do_this()` function needs *this* *or* *that*..." or similar. When everything is in one big code block everyone reading it needs to start from zero. A function with a clear name (or a comment to compensate for the poor naming as I did above, "proxy") and only a few lines of code can be reviewed by everyone without much background knowledge about the bigger problem.

In short, I took your code that was specifically created to do one thing and broke it down into a few functions that I used to rebuild something similar to your original idea. By doing that I made it easier to see flaws, talk about design decisions. If a function of 2-4 lines can be reviewed by 10000 people and they don't see a problem, it's very unlikely that that function is the problem (in itself). By building blocks of small functions with a clear purpose, bughunting becomes a lot more available for everyone, not only people deeply involved in the particular problem you're solving.

I now see that I used a function template from `<algorithm>` that may be unfamiliar: `std::for_each`. In this case, it could be replaced by:

```
for(char ch : sequence) display(ch);
```

Come to think of it, that's even clearer.

<sub>If this wasn't the overview you sought, just comment and point out the parts you want to get explained and I'll try again</sub>

Comment: Thanks but the result is still the same, there is still slash ( / ) at the end if a newline follows the spinner. The backspace character is ignored. I guess I could work around that in my program but I can't figure out why that happens.

Comment: There's not a single newline in the example above so I'm not following exactly. I'll try it out on a windows machine soon.

Comment: @n00B I compilid it with VS2019 and ran it in a Powershell - looks ok. Do I understand you correctly if the problem is that _when_ you print a newline _after_ having run the spinner, it leaves a \ ? If that's what you mean check out the update I made.

Comment: Thanks for your help but it is still giving the same result. It does not work well with text before and after the spinner. I think @someprogrammerdude kind of explained it. However I can work around this in my program. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @n00B You are welcome! I updated it with text both before and after the spinner. Do you mean that the program above doesn't print `Spinner: [ ]` and keeps the spinner running between the backets?

Comment: Thanks, give me an overview of what you did. The code is a bit over my head!

Comment: @n00B You're welcome! Will do when I come home. 8-10 hours.

Comment: @n00B Just home - added some explanations for why I did what I did, but I feel I may not have explained every detail. Having a methodology of breaking down a problem is usually what eventually makes the problem go away though.

Comment: Amazing! thank you, you did good explaining, I can't upvote yet but I would if I can!

Comment: @n00B Great! Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

The backspace character doesn't actually delete the previous character, all it does is move the cursor itself back one "space". It's the combination of backspace *followed* by writing another character that does the overwrite or "delete" the character.

Also, the backspace only goes as far as the beginning of the current line. Once you have printed a newline you can't go back "up" a line with a backspace.

On Windows you might be able to get better results by using the [Windows console functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions), and on POSIX systems (like Linux or macOS) maybe [VT100 escape codes](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm).

Comment: the first sentence was so helpful that, makes sense. But the tab character overwrites the " / " why doesn't a newline.

Comment: @n00B Much like the backspace, the newline doesn't really print a character, it just causes the cursor to do gown to the next line. On old systems (and still on Windows) you needed a carriage-return `'\r'` as well to get to the beginning of the line, otherwise the cursor went down one line but still on the same position.